# How to get user roles using query in jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, switch-statement, user-roles

i am new in java i want role based access using switch statement but when i execute query and provide user role for example(user or admin) then user log-in well but if i leave (role='') empty in query then query not execute so well and jump in else statement.Second if i use prepared statement then how i can get user role thanks.Here is my code.

```
<%
  String userid = request.getParameter("username");   
  String pwd = request.getParameter("password");
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auto_lube","root", "password");

  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs;
  rs = st.executeQuery("select * from users where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "' and role=''");  

  if (rs.next()) {           
    String username =  rs.getString("uname");
    String email =  rs.getString("email");
    String rolle =  rs.getString("role");
    session.setAttribute("customer_name", username); 

    int usser =  rs.getInt("id");
    session.setAttribute("customer_id", usser);
    switch(rs.getInt(rolle)) {                  
      case 1:
        if (rolle.equals("admin")) {                  
          response.sendRedirect("adminPage.jsp");
          break;
        }

      case 2:
        if (rolle.equals("user")) {                 
          response.sendRedirect("user.jsp");
        }
        break;

      case 3:
        if (rolle.equals("assistant")) {                 
          response.sendRedirect("assistant.jsp");
        }
        break;

      case 4:
        if (rolle.equals("supplier")) {                 
          response.sendRedirect("supplier.jsp");
        }
        break;

      default:
        break;
    } 
  } else {
  out.print("invalid");
  } 
%>
```

Comment: st.executeQuery("select * from users where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "' and role=''"); SQL injection source

Comment: If you are not passing any role then you can redirect him to users.jsp and also your control should not come at JDBC code.

Comment: i putt double quot after role it show error

Comment: if i put user role then how to execute switch statement because  i should write multiple query for multiple role its not good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations, you put in only one piece of code a lot of bad practices !

You put a lot of scriptlet in JSP. You'd better use a servlet for this processing, and only use JSP for the view (display) part. Servlet are true Java classes and as such are easier to write and test.

You concatenate user input strings in a query without using prepared statements (but I acknowledged you noticed it :-) ). **Never do that**, it is a open trap for SQL injection (just google for it)

You store in database cleartext passwords. Good practices recommend to only store a non inversible hash of the password. If the database is compromised, the attacker cannot get passwords.

You impose `role = ''` in the query. I would be very surprised if you ever find an `admin` role with that !

You use the role for choosing to what page redirect. It is not by itself a bad practice, but it can be if you do not test that user has a valid role in redirected page. Common usage is to have one single page with parts displayed only according to role (`<c:if>` blocs in JSP).

And what means `rs.getInt(rolle)` ? You get rolle from result set, fine use it directly and test if it is null before doing any `rolle.equals(...)` (NPE is not far)

For the prepared statement, you could do:

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("select * from users where uname=? and pass=?");
st.setString(1, userid);
st.setString(2, pwd);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

That way, not only you are protected from SQL injection, but you get a line from database from `userid`, `pwd` whatever the role can be.

Edit :

After that query, you can still read any attribute from `users` table :

```
  if (rs.next()) {           
    String username =  rs.getString("uname");
    String email =  rs.getString("email");
    String rolle =  rs.getString("role");
    session.setAttribute("customer_name", username); 

    int usser =  rs.getInt("id");
    session.setAttribute("customer_id", usser);
```

And the tests should be

```
if (rolle == null || role.isEmpty()) {
    // process no role case first - it deals with the null role problem
}
else if (role.equals("admin") {
    ...
}
...
else {
    // process for unknown role
}
```

Comment: bundle of thanks please share a link for any related example for clear understanding.

Comment: kindly tell me if i use only above prepared Statement without using role then how i can use switch statement.thanks

Comment: @Balajeet, you are making a confusion between input and output query parameters. See my edit.